# Apache Mahout Math VectorWritable missing in 0.6?

Tags: csv, hadoop, mahout, k-means

I am working on a kmeans clustering by using Mahout. However, it looks like Mahout's kmeans does not support CSV file, then I am trying to write a specific sequence file generator.

The strange thing is that I am trying to use **org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable** class, but it seems this class does not in the **mahout-math-0.6.jar** package.

So is there anyone knows where is the VectorWritable class?

Thank you so much!

Jilong

Answer (score 2):

Ever since, it has been in the `core.jar`.

However its package name is a bit misleading (`org.apache.mahout.math`).